# xorg input driver

Tags: c, c++11, xorg

I need to write a xinput driver for a virtual device, e.g. http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~whot/xf86-input-random. The device is connected to a LAN. The client for this device is written in C++. Is it possible to use C++ code in this driver or must the whole project be C only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `Xorg` driver is just an [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) shared object plugin following some documented convention. In principle, how you obtain that `.so` is your own business (you could in theory write it manually bit by bit if you have centuries of your time to lose).
In principle, you could link the `libstdc++.so` to your shared object (since one can link shared objects to other ones). I guess that you would compile and link your plugin with `g++` and perhaps explicitly need to link with `-lstdc++`

However, I guess that it might be unsafe. Perhaps C++ ABI requires some specific things to be executed by the [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0).

So you might try, but I won't be surprised if something does not work as you want (e.g. exception handling). It could depend upon the version of the C++ library and the version of the C library and the version of the compiler.... I guess that it might work better with recent `g++`, recent `libc`, recent `libstdc++` ....

Read [Drupper's paper: How to Write Shared Libraries](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Paper/3198168.aspx)

Make your driver free software, and publish very quickly its source code, so you could get some help from the Xorg community (even when your driver is incomplete). Use probably a recent `Xorg`....